# Updating Source Domain in GTM Server Side is not working

Tags: google-tag-manager, server-side

I have changed the source domain from googletagmanager to mysitedomain. But I am not able to the see gtm js script loading in Sources Tab. Also the preview option is also not working in web container and not showing any pageview coming in server container. What could be the issue here. Please advise

the preview option is also not working in the  web container and not showing any pageview coming in the  server container. What could be the issue her?. Please advise